# How to split multiple mixed numeric values separated by a comma and hyphen into a list of numbers in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have this table in my Raw Schema in Snowflake:

| ID | SHIFT | TYPE | DOW_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 | A1 | ,2-5, |
| 1 | 102 | A8 | 1-3,5-6, |
| 2 | 153 | X5 | 1-3,5-6 |
| 2 | 150 | Q9 | ,1-3,5-6, |
| 3 | 567 | Q3 | ,1-3,5-6 |
| 4 | 345 | T6 | 1-3,5, |
| 5 | 555 | H6H | ,1-3,5, |
| 6 | 353 | HU78 | ,1-3,5 |
| 1 | 213 | B5 | 1,3-4,7, |
| 23 | 875 | J4 | ,1,3-4,7, |
| 23 | 607 | S3 | ,1,3-4,7 |
| 56 | 452 | A3 | ,7, |
| 12 | 587 | ADLS2 | ,7 |
| 12 | 839 | QWRETY4 | 7, |
| 13 | 466 | R5 | , |
| 14 | 743 | Y7 | ,2,4,6, |
| 14 | 432 | E32 | 2,4,6 |
| 31 | 117 | OP9 | 2,4,6, |
| 11 | 109 | TRE5 | ,2,4,6 |
| 20 | 217 | TUYP8 | 1-6,7 |

I need to turn the "DOW_NUM" Column into the NEW_DOW_NUM column as shown below:

| ID | SHIFT | TYPE | DOW_NUM | NEW_DOW_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 | A1 | ,2-5, | 2,5 |
| 1 | 102 | A8 | 1-3,5-6, | 1,2,3,5,6 |
| 2 | 153 | X5 | 1-3,5-6 | 1,2,3,5,6 |
| 2 | 150 | Q9 | ,1-3,5-6, | 1,2,3,5,6 |
| 3 | 567 | Q3 | ,1-3,5-6 | 1,2,3,5,6 |
| 4 | 345 | T6 | 1-3,5, | 1,2,3,5 |
| 5 | 555 | H6H | ,1-3,5, | 1,2,3,5 |
| 6 | 353 | HU78 | ,1-3,5 | 1,2,3,5 |
| 1 | 213 | B5 | 1,3-4,7, | 1,3,4,7 |
| 23 | 875 | J4 | ,1,3-4,7, | 1,3,4,7 |
| 23 | 607 | S3 | ,1,3-4,7 | 1,3,4,7 |
| 56 | 452 | A3 | ,7, | 7 |
| 12 | 587 | ADLS2 | ,7 | 7 |
| 12 | 839 | QWRETY4 | 7, | 7 |
| 13 | 466 | R5 | , |  |
| 14 | 743 | Y7 | ,2,4,6, | 2,4,6 |
| 14 | 432 | E32 | 2,4,6 | 2,4,6 |
| 31 | 117 | OP9 | 2,4,6, | 2,4,6 |
| 11 | 109 | TRE5 | ,2,4,6 | 2,4,6 |
| 20 | 217 | TUYP8 | 1-6,7 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |

How do I do this in Snowflake? The "DOW_NUM" column will always have a min and max number value of 1 and 7 respectively, as the numbers represent the days of the week, the issue is that some values have hyphens and commas in different combinations.

I am posting this question because this is something I had to solve in my own work, I already have the answer but I am posting it to help the Stack Overflow community in case anyone comes across a similar problem. If you have a better solution than the one I will post please share it so I can understand other ways of getting my final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using [array_generate_range](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_generate_range) and [split_to_table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table) functions:

```
WITH T AS (
SELECT 
  TB.ID, 
  TB.SHIFT, 
  TB.TYPE, 
  TB.DOW_NUM,
  NULLIF(SP.VALUE, '') AS COMMA_SPLIT_VAL
FROM TBL_NAME TB, 
LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(TB.DOW_NUM, ',') SP
) 
SELECT 
  T.ID, 
  T.SHIFT, 
  T.TYPE, 
  T.DOW_NUM, 
  LISTAGG(GR.VALUE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GR.VALUE) NEW_DOW_NUM
FROM T, 
TABLE(
   FLATTEN(
           ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(SPLIT_PART(T.COMMA_SPLIT_VAL, '-', 1), 
           COALESCE(NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(T.COMMA_SPLIT_VAL, '-', 2), ''),
           SPLIT_PART(T.COMMA_SPLIT_VAL, '-', 1)) +1, 1),  
           OUTER => TRUE
          )
      ) GR
GROUP BY T.ID, T.SHIFT, T.TYPE, T.DOW_NUM
ORDER BY T.ID, T.SHIFT, T.TYPE;
```

Sample Of The Output:

```
ID  SHIFT   TYPE    DOW_NUM       NEW_DOW_NUM
0   101     A1      ,2-5,         2, 3, 4, 5
1   102     A8      1-3,5-6,      1, 2, 3, 5, 6
1   213     B5      1,3-4,7,      1, 3, 4, 7
2   150     Q9      ,1-3,5-6,     1, 2, 3, 5, 6
2   153     X5      1-3,5-6       1, 2, 3, 5, 6
3   567     Q3      ,1-3,5-6      1, 2, 3, 5, 6
4   345     T6      1-3,5,        1, 2, 3, 5
5   555     H6H     ,1-3,5,       1, 2, 3, 5
6   353     HU78    ,1-3,5        1, 2, 3, 5
12  839     QWRETY4 7,            7
13  466     R5       ,
```

Explanation:
The `SPLIT_TO_TABLE(TB.DOW_NUM, ',')` will split the `DOW_NUM` by the comma, the results of the split may be a single value i.e. 1 or a range of values, i.e. 1-6.

The `ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE` function returns an array of integer values according to the specified range, the [syntax](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_generate_range) of the function is:

> ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(start , stop, step)

Where the stop value is not included, so the last generated value will be `stop - 1`, *when the step is 1*.

The arguments of this function will be as the following:

- start: `SPLIT_PART(T.COMMA_SPLIT_VAL, '-', 1)`, either the split value is x or x-y this will return x.
- stop: `COALESCE(NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(T.COMMA_SPLIT_VAL, '-', 2), '')...`, if the split value is a range (x-y) it will return y, if it is a single value it will return an empty string, so the `nullif` function is used to return null instead. The `COALESCE` function is used to return the end sub-range value if existed, and if not, (the split value is a single number) it will return that value itself. The +1 is used to include the end sub-range value.
- step: 1.

e.g.

- The split value is 1: `ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(1, 2, 1)`.
- The split value is 1-6: `ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(1, 7, 1)`.
- the split value is empty string: `ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(null, null, 1)` returning a null.

The [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten) function is used to explode the `ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE` values into rows.

> FLATTEN is a table function that takes a VARIANT, OBJECT, or ARRAY column and produces a lateral view (i.e. an inline view that contains correlation referring to other tables that precede it in the FROM clause).

The `OUTER => TRUE` argument is optional and is used here to return an empty row value (when the `DOW_NUM` value contains neither a single value nor a sub-range, i.e. `DOW_NUM = ','`)

> A [table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-table) function returns a set of rows for each input row. The returned set can contain zero, one, or more rows. Each row can contain one or more columns.

To get more understanding, try to run the query without the aggregation:

```
WITH t AS (...
SELECT t.id, t.shift, t.type, t.dow_num, 
       gr.value NEW_DOW_NUM
FROM t, 
 TABLE (...
```

Comment: Could you please explain this part of your code in your answer as well please, I'm new to using some of these functions. `TABLE( FLATTEN( ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(SPLIT_PART(T.COMMA_SPLIT_VAL, '-', 1), COALESCE(NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(T.COMMA_SPLIT_VAL, '-', 2), ''), SPLIT_PART(T.COMMA_SPLIT_VAL, '-', 1)) +1, 1), OUTER => TRUE ) ) GR`

Also please accept the edits and then I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
WITH RECURSIVE numbers AS (
SELECT 1 AS NUM
UNION ALL
SELECT NUM + 1 FROM numbers WHERE NUM < 7
),
-- Split the DOW_NUM string into individual days
SPLIT_VALUES AS (
SELECT 
    ID,
    SHIFT,
    TYPE,
    DOW_NUM,
    F.VALUE,
    IFF(POSITION('-' IN F.VALUE::string) > 0, 
        TRY_TO_NUMBER(SPLIT_PART(F.VALUE::string, '-', 1)), 
        TRY_TO_NUMBER(F.VALUE::string)
          ) as START_DAY,
    IFF(POSITION('-' IN F.VALUE::string) > 0, 
        TRY_TO_NUMBER(SPLIT_PART(F.VALUE::string, '-', 2)), 
        TRY_TO_NUMBER(F.VALUE::string)
          ) as END_DAY
FROM 
  WORK_DAY_INFO, 
  LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DOW_NUM, ',,', ','), ',,', ','), ',,', ','), ',')) as F
),
-- Generate individual days from the ranges
EXPANDED_VALUES AS (
SELECT 
    ID,
    SHIFT,
    TYPE,
    DOW_NUM,
    N.NUM AS DAY
FROM SPLIT_VALUES AS SV
LEFT JOIN numbers AS N
ON N.NUM BETWEEN SV.START_DAY AND SV.END_DAY
),
-- Create NEW_DOW_NUM COLUMN
NEW_WORK_DAY_INFO AS (
SELECT 
   ID,
   SHIFT,
   TYPE,
   DOW_NUM,
   LISTAGG(DAY::string, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DAY) AS NEW_DOW_NUM
FROM 
   EXPANDED_VALUES
GROUP BY 
    ID,
    SHIFT,
    TYPE,
    DOW_NUM
)
SELECT *
FROM NEW_WORK_DAY_INFO;
```